# Set two JTextArea side by side netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, textarea

I try to set two `JTextField` side by side, I use Netbeans, this is what I already do :

[image]

I can't arrive to set them **50% 50%**, and when I maximize my frame this what happen:

[image]

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use GridBag Layout. Then open the layout editing (right click the layout) and give all text areas a width of 1.0 and fill of "both".

Comment: Thank you @brummfondel this really help me and work really good thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Is your problem that only the one textField changes is width?? If yes you can use a GroupLayout like this:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
setContentPane(contentPane);

JTextField textField = new JTextField();
textField.setColumns(10);

JTextField textField_1 = new JTextField();
textField_1.setColumns(10);
GroupLayout gl_contentPane = new GroupLayout(contentPane);
gl_contentPane.setHorizontalGroup(
        gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(textField, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 199, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(textField_1, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 215, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
gl_contentPane.setVerticalGroup(
        gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                    .addComponent(textField_1, Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(textField, Alignment.LEADING, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 82, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap(159, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
contentPane.setLayout(gl_contentPane);
```

Comment: is that code with Netbeans?, if yes, how you do to get this code this is my goal!

Comment: I dont understand you very well, my IDE is eclipse the code can work with any IDE, i generated through WindowBuilder but i think the plugin is only for eclipse.

Comment: mmm, ok, i don't want to use code, i want to generate it with the Netbeans IDE